# Handling multiple push notifications got error

Tags: ios, error-handling, push-notification

I handle push notification when the screen is on by automatically push to a detailViewController. It works fine when there is one or two push notification as I can push each detailViewController on top of each other and pop it back. However, app crash when I have to pop back more than two detailViewControllers. It happens only in iOS 7+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set notification Id

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
   if(app.applicationIconBadgeNumber!=0)
   {
        app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = app.applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1;
    }

    NSString *aps =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]];


    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]] forKeys:@[@"notifyText"]];
        [arrNotificationData addObject:dict];
        [self showNotificationInActiveMode:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]];
    }


   if ([aps isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:[aps intValue]];       
    }
    if ([aps isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:[aps intValue]];
    }
    if ([aps isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:[aps intValue]];
    }
    if ([aps isEqualToString:@"4"])
    {
        [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:[aps intValue]];
    }if ([aps isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:[aps intValue]];
    }


}
```

Use singleton class as base class and check for ID and the push and pop the view.

```
@interface CustomViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(appBecomeActive)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

-(void)appBecomeActive
{

    int val=[UserDefault getpushnotificationid];
    if(val!=0){

        [self checkforpushnotification];
    }
}


-(void)checkforpushnotification
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    int val=[UserDefault getpushnotificationid];
    [UserDefault setpushnotificationid:0];


    //.: if current view is profile or setting just dismiss it.because they are present

    switch (val)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            if( [self checkIfControllerExist:[DealsViewController class]])
            {
                return;
            }else{
                detailViewController *VC = (detailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCView"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
            }
        }
            break;
}
}
```

Now use bace class in your class

```
@interface detailViewController : CustomViewController
```